# What is the appropriate semantic markup for form label help sub-text

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Some form elements in a form may require text to explain the function of said element. I'm thinking of encapsulating this text in a paragraph element, as follows,

```css
label p {
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="form-input-1">Label Text
    <p>Label explainer/help text</p>
  </label>
  <input id="form-input-1" />
</div>
```

My question is: is the `<p>` element the most semantic element for this use? In my opinion, the label sub-text is a type of sub-title and one could argue that it may call for a `<h*>` element. But, these are often used for outlines, and I don't believe this would be super semantic here. Would a `<span>`, make sense here, as these *may* be used to mark off parts of inline flow elements?

Please, share your thoughts!

Comment: I'd say the span element is more than enough, since it has no associated meaning, and the label element itself already provides a bit of detail for its respective input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) elements can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), which means they can't contain headings or paragraph elements, which are [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content).

Additionally, the MDN Docs note that [headings should not be used within labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#headings) because that "interferes with many kinds of assistive technologies".

If additional form field instructions are needed beyond what would reasonably fit within a label, you should use a separate element, outside of the label—and tie it to the input using the `aria-describedby` attribute, as outlined on the W3C's [Web Accessibility Tutorial on Form Instructions](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/#in-line-instructions).

Here's an example of that approach:

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="input">Label Text</label>
  <span id="instructions">Additional instructions lorem ipsum</span>
  <input id="input" aria-describedby="instructions" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Sean, notice that if we placing elements _outside_ of the `<label>` element, then, we lose the label-like, click-forwarding, behavior of `label` for the instructions, which is what I'm going after. Also, what would be a "reasonable" amount of text that would fit in a label? Can we extend the notion of a label to include instruction text?

Comment: If your additional instructions never need to include interactive content such as links, you can include it all as a label—provided it's only marked up with phrasing content. Also note that you can have _multiple_ labels for a single `input`, as long as they're not nested. @seebiscuit

Comment: Hey, Sean, read over the [Flow Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) list again, I noticed that `<label>` is in there as well,

Comment: @seebiscuit Yes, labels are flow content. They can only contain phrasing content though.

Comment: Just noticed, the [Technical Summary on the label doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) and it effectively validates what you've shared! Thank you for helping me understand the `<label>` element better 

Answer (score 1):

In complex forms there are mulitple sections, headings, hints, helper texts an so on used as explanation. So there are multiple ways to add descriptions and helper texts to a form:

1. `<span>` is the simplest form. Add it to the label-element.
2. `<fieldset>` with `<legend>` wraps fields together and adds a descripition.
3. `<section>` can give additional structure and information to a form.
4. `<p>` can be used to add addtional information i.e. to the whole form or a form-section
5. `<div>` is used by Google in Maerial Design for a text field helper line

Often done but NOT to be used for farer explanation should be texts in placeholders.

In your example I believe a `span` within the `label`should be a good solution which will match the semantic.

---

**ADDITOINAL INFORMATION**

Complex HTML code example from MDN:

```
    <form method="post">
        <h1>Payment form</h1>
        <p>Required fields are followed by <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>.</p>
        <section>
            <h2>Contact information</h2>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Title</legend>
              <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label for="title_1">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_1" name="title" value="A">
                      Ace
                    </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label for="title_2">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_2" name="title" value="K" >
                      King
                    </label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label for="title_3">
                      <input type="radio" id="title_3" name="title" value="Q">
                      Queen
                    </label>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <p>
              <label for="name">
                <span>Name: </span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="username">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="mail">
                <span>E-mail: </span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
              <input type="email" id="mail" name="usermail">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="pwd">
                <span>Password: </span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
              <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password">
            </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2>Payment information</h2>
            <p>
              <label for="card">
                <span>Card type:</span>
              </label>
              <select id="card" name="usercard">
                <option value="visa">Visa</option>
                <option value="mc">Mastercard</option>
                <option value="amex">American Express</option>
              </select>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="number">
                <span>Card number:</span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
              </label>
                <input type="tel" id="number" name="cardnumber">
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="date">
                <span>Expiration date:</span>
                <strong><abbr title="required">*</abbr></strong>
                <em>formatted as mm/dd/yyyy</em>
              </label>
              <input type="date" id="date" name="expiration">
            </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p> <button type="submit">Validate the payment</button> </p>
        </section>
    </form>
```

Link to see MDN form live:
https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/forms/html-form-structure/payment-form.html

Link to wider MDN explanations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/How_to_structure_a_web_form#common_html_structures_used_with_forms*

Link to example Google Material Design:
https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/helper-text

Comment: Thank you for the time you've taken to post this answer. While you've pointed out some interesting parts of a form, unfortunately, you failed to point to any standard, or reason, describing the particular problem I'm asking on. You see, my question is a general question regarding form documentation. I'm am not looking to change our current design. Rather, it's a specific question about usage within our requirements. Again, thank you for your thoughtful response!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any definitive answer or resource so you can only get opinions. Here's mine:

I'd start by thinking about how to markup the whole form. I think [the semantic form style described in MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/How_to_structure_a_web_form#common_html_structures_used_with_forms) is a pretty good place to start. Especially the part that a form is logically a list of form controls so you should have `<ul>` and `<li>` elements wrapping the controls in semantic order. However, I think it has one problematic part where it uses logically markup like

```
<label><input>text</label>
```

for radio buttons, but

```
<label>text<input></label>
```

for text inputs. I'd highly prefer that the markup order doesn't change depending on the input type (checkbox/radio button vs text/email/password). To do that in practice, you probably want to always use markup like

```
<li class="checkbox">
  <label for=id1>text</label>
  <input id=id1>
</li>
```

which you can then style by using e.g. `li.checkbox { display: flex; ... }` and reorder the label and input visually as needed. Obviously the `class` is needed only for styling but it is not needed for semantics. If browsers ever implement `:has()` then there would be no need for a `class` at all.

As for the help text for the input, *in theory*, you would want to use

```
<li class="checkbox">
  <label for=id1>text</label>
  <input id=id1>
  <label for=id1 class=help>help content here</label>
</li>
```

because by spec it should be possible to attach multiple labels to a single input. However, as far as I know, this doesn't work in practice with the software that's commonly used by blind people needing accessibility aids.

As such, the next question is how do you think this help text should be used by all the following groups?

1. Users with vision without JavaScript support. (Note that this group includes most search engines.)
2. Blind persons without JavaScript support.
3. Users with vision with JavaScript support. (Note that this group includes some search engines.)

As far as I know, there's no good answer to cater for all the 3 groups perfectly. Note that for practical support for a yet another group "Blind persons with JavaScript support" you can use any markup you want and use ARIA attributes to make it accessible. Overall, the best I can think of is as follows:

```
<li class="checkbox">
  <label for=id1>text</label>
  <input id=id1 aria-describedby=id2>
  <aside id=id2>help content here</aside>
</li>
```

That should be good enough to attach the help content to the input for accessibility tools, the help content is semantically additional content so `<aside>` should be okay for both blind and visual users and you can use CSS only to make the `<aside>` visible only when the input is focused. Also note that `<aside>` allows any content for help, incuding videos in iframes, not just text. Of course, if you need user to click within the `<aside>` element you cannot use `input:focus` to toggle the element visible but you need to use some kind of JavaScript support. Exact details depend on which group you want to cater for most and if you want to have the help text available to all groups.

This markup also contains all the information you need to wrangle it as needed by JavaScript. For some non-JavaScript styling options you might want to wrap the label and input in some wrapper element so that you can position those as a group separate from `<aside>` element. In that case markup like

```
<li class="checkbox">
  <div>
    <label for=id1>text</label>
    <input id=id1 aria-describedby=id2>
  </div>
  <aside id=id2>help content here</aside>
</li>
```

could be a good option. You can target that classless `<div>` element by selector `form li.checkbox>div` if needed. One could then use e.g. `display:grid` or `subgrid` for the `li.checkbox` and e.g. `display:flex` for the `li.checkbox>div` to position everything nicely. However, if you do that, you cannot nicely toggle the visibility of the help text simply by using style like `input:not(:focus) + aside { display: none; }`. I think you can survive without the wrapper `<div>` element if you use `display:grid` for `li.checkbox` because that allows positioning stuff in 2D unlike `flex`.

And if you need to support users with vision but without support for CSS, then I don't have a good solution. Using the above mentioned semantic list markup results in bullet points in addition to form inputs which could look pretty messy for non-CSS users.